# Swift `for-in` loop Range and ClosedRange errors

Tags: swift, for-loop, range, for-in-loop

I'm attempting to write simple Swift `for` loops like so:

```
for i in [0...10] {
    // ...
}

for i in [0..<10] {
    // ...
}
```

These `for-in` loops over a range are important due to the absence of classic C-style `for` loops in Swift. I am attempting to  enumerate over any array of Ints built via Swift's `...` and `..<` syntax.

Note that if I construct an array of Ints "manually" rather than use `[...]` or `[..<]`, it works fine:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
    // this works fine 
}
```

But the `[0..<5]` loops produce errors basically any time I try to use the value `i`:

```
let _ = i + 1
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
- Binary operator `'+'` cannot be applied to operands of type `'ClosedRange<Int>'` and `'Int'`  

- Binary operator `'+'` cannot be applied to operands of type `'Range<Int>'` and `'Int'  `
```

I have also tried this:

```
let _ = String(i)
```

And I get:

```
Ambiguous reference to initializer `'init(_:)'`
```

Why are these simple `for-in` loops not working?

Why are the errors referencing `Range` and `ClosedRange`? I am expecting an `Int`.

Comment: Is this really worth a self-answered question, if the solution is immediately found in the language guide?

Comment: @MartinR I just spent way too long trying to fix this myself. **Attempting to SEO the error messages.** Potential common misunderstanding: it's a proper `Range` type, you're not creating. "an array of Ints" as one might think.

Comment: This question is not a "typo"... I'm very specifically trying to record the differences between looping over a `[0, 1, 2, 3]` Int array and a `0...3` Range (and the error messages generated when you mistakenly loop over a `[0...3] Array<Range>`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Swift ranges are written as `0...10`, ***not*** `[0...10]`.

---

`[0...10]` creates a single-item array. The first item in the array is a `0...10` range.

Using `for i in [0...10]` thus iterates over that single-item array, *not* the range itself. The iterated value `i` will be of type `Range` or `ClosedRange`.

To iterate over each `Int` in the range, as you expect to be doing, use the range `0...10` *without* the brackets:

```
for i in 0...10 {
    // ...
}

for i in 0..<10 {
    // ...
}
```

---

> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html
>
> You can also use for-in loops with numeric ranges. This example prints the first few entries in a five-times table:
>
> ```
> for index in 1...5 {
>     print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
> }
> ```
>
> The sequence being iterated over is a range of numbers from 1 to 5, inclusive, as indicated by the use of the closed range operator `(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

## Range

There is a type in Swift called `Range`. It is a `struct` and can be used like:

```
Range.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 0, upper: 10))
```

Since it's very common to use ranges in code, there is a syntactic sugar for this like:

```
0..<10
```

So when you say `[0...10]` it's like you say `[Range.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 0, upper: 10))]` and that is not what you are looking for.

Instead you should iterate over the `range` itself like:

```
for i in 0...10 {
    print(i)
}
```

---

Extra:

`ClosedRange` is similar to `Range` and of course you can get rid of the `init` keyword in Swift:

```
ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 0, upper: 10)) // 0...10
```